# GATT library directly reading characteristic values without iterating through services

Tags: linux, bluetooth, go

I'm trying to use go on a raspberry pi to query bluetooth low energy devices.  It's functional, I can connect to the device I want and iterate through the services and characteristics of the connected device.  Now I'm just trying to streamline things and just read/write the values I'm interested in.  It isn't working.

Code:

```golang
func onPeriphConnected(p gatt.Peripheral, err error) {
    fmt.Println("Connected")
    defer p.Device().CancelConnection(p)

    if err := p.SetMTU(500); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to set MTU, err: %s\n", err)

    }

    batteryServiceId := gatt.MustParseUUID("180f")


    // Direct read attempt (not working)


    batterySerivce := gatt.NewService(batteryServiceId)
    batteryLevelUUID := gatt.MustParseUUID("2a19")
    batteryChar := gatt.NewCharacteristic(batteryLevelUUID,batterySerivce,gatt.Property(0x12),0,0)
    e, err := p.ReadCharacteristic(batteryChar)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to read battery level, err: %s\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }


    // iterate services read (working)

    ss, err := p.DiscoverServices(nil)  

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to discover services, err: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    for _, s := range ss {
        if(s.UUID().Equal(batteryServiceId)) {
            fmt.Println("Found the battery service")

        // Discovery characteristics
            cs, err := p.DiscoverCharacteristics(nil, s)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Failed to discover characteristics, err: %s\n", err)
                continue
            }

            for _, c := range cs {
                msg := "  Characteristic  " + c.UUID().String()
                if len(c.Name()) > 0 {
                    msg += " (" + c.Name() + ")"
                }
                msg += "\n    properties    " + c.Properties().String()
                fmt.Println(msg)

                if (c.Properties() & gatt.CharRead) != 0 {
                    b, err := p.ReadCharacteristic(c)
                    if err != nil {
                        fmt.Printf("Failed to read characteristic, err: %s\n", err)
                        continue
                    }
                    fmt.Printf("    value         %x\n", b)
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Results:

```
Connected
[10 0 0 1]
Found the battery service
  Characteristic  2a19 (Battery Level)
    properties    read notify 
    value         53
```

You can see where I expect to get a hex value of 53 I'm instead getting an array of [10 0 0 1].  I'm pretty new to go so I'm probably missing something here or just assembling my read incorrectly.  Any pointers are much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A link to the [appropriate documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/paypal/gatt) would be advisable.  I don't know if *this* link is correct as there seem to be multiple different versions of package `gatt`.

Edit: see also https://godoc.org/github.com/paypal/gatt/examples/service#NewBatteryService at https://github.com/paypal/gatt/blob/master/examples/service/battery.go, which appears to show the right way of creating a battery service directly.  Original answer below.

---

Having had a quick scan through said documentation, two things leap out at me:

1. The battery *level* ID is `2a19`.  The battery *service* ID is `180f`.  You use:

   ```
   batteryServiceId := gatt.MustParseUUID("180f")
   batterySerivce := gatt.NewService(batteryServiceId)
   batteryChar := gatt.NewCharacteristic(batteryLevelUUID, batterySerivce,
       gatt.Property(0x12), 0, 0)
   e, err := p.ReadCharacteristic(batteryChar)
   ```

   (I kept variable name spellings, but added a bit of white space to fit better on the StackOverflow display.)  You never call `NewDescriptor` nor either of `AddDescriptor` or `SetDescriptors` on `batteryChar`.  Are such calls *required?*  I don't know; the documentation doesn't say.  But the call that *works* uses `DiscoverServices` followed by `DiscoverCharacteristics`, which perhaps does create these (documented but undescribed) Descriptors.  They look like they interpose themselves in value-oriented operations, so they might be critical.

   Looking further at the code, after or instead of creating a characteristic directly, I think you do have to at least link the characteristic back into the service.  The right call might be `AddCharacteristic` or `SetCharacteristics`.  See [this chunk of code in `DiscoverCharacteristics`](https://github.com/paypal/gatt/blob/4ae819d591cfc94c496c45deb55928469542beec/peripheral_linux.go#L128-L153).
2. (Minor.)  `gatt.Property(0x12)` is definitely the wrong way to construct the constant.  You probably should use:

   ```
   gatt.Property.CharRead | gatt.Property.CharNotify
   ```

Comment: That is the documentation.

I appreciate your comments. I've looked through the links and I'm still not getting anywhere. I may be approaching the problem incorrectly.  I want to read a known characteristic and I have a peripheral object (p). Since p.ReadCharacteristic takes a characteristic object I'm trying to make an empty one and then since that needs a service I'm making one of those.  rying to use that characteristic object I've created with my p just doesn't go. Same results even when using what you posted above. Maybe I just have to iterate even though it is wasteful.

Comment: Also, FYI, item 2 doesn't work.  It would be great if it did and there's probably a way to make it happen that I just don't know about, but as written it's a no go.  Thanks though, I really do appreciate it.